# Stretch a texture in XNA 4.0?

Tags: c#, xna

I can't figure anyway to do this, I don't want to scale it with .Draw, I want to just change the width.

Comment: The overload of `Draw` that takes a `Vector2` parameter for scale is not suitable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way is using .Draw particularly if you are scaling a lot, especially as your object should handle its own drawing capabilities.

You can render the texture using a render target at the size you want, and then saving the render target texture.

Searching for a quick code example came up with the following which is saying the same thing:

[How to resize and save a Texture2D in XNA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664279/how-to-resize-and-save-a-texture2d-in-xna)