# C# - reverse image bytes quickly?

Tags: c#, image, arrays, reverse

I'm trying to determine the optimal way to flip an image across the Y axis.  For every pixel, there are 4 bytes, and each set of 4 bytes needs to remain together in order but get shifted.  Here's the best I've come up with so far.

This only takes .1-.2s for a 1280x960 image, but with video such performance is crippling.  Any suggestions?

**Initial implementation**

```
        private void ReverseFrameInPlace(int width, int height, int bytesPerPixel, ref byte[] framePixels)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch s = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

        int stride = width * bytesPerPixel;
        int halfStride = stride / 2;
        int byteJump = bytesPerPixel * 2;
        int length = stride * height;
        byte pix;

        for (int i = 0, a = stride, b = stride - bytesPerPixel;
            i < length; i++)
        {
            if (b % bytesPerPixel == 0)
            {
                b -= byteJump;
            }
            if (i > 0 && i % halfStride == 0)
            {
                i = a;
                a += stride;
                b = a - bytesPerPixel;
                if (i >= length)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }

            pix = framePixels[i];
            framePixels[i] = framePixels[b];
            framePixels[b++] = pix;
        }

        s.Stop();
        System.Console.WriteLine("ReverseFrameInPlace: {0}", s.Elapsed);
    }
```

**Revision #1**

Revised with indexes and Buffer.BlockCopy per SLaks and Alexei.  Also added a Parallel.For since the indexes allow for it.

```
    int[] pixelIndexF = null;
    int[] pixelIndexB = null;
    private void ReverseFrameInPlace(int width, int height, int bytesPerPixel, byte[] framePixels)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch s = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

        if (pixelIndexF == null)// || pixelIndex.Length != (width * height))
        {
            int stride = width * bytesPerPixel;
            int length = stride * height;

            pixelIndexF = new int[width * height / 2];
            pixelIndexB = new int[width * height / 2];
            for (int i = 0, a = stride, b = stride, index = 0;
                i < length; i++)
            {
                b -= bytesPerPixel;
                if (i > 0 && i % (width / 2 )== 0)
                {
                    //i = a;
                    i += width / 2;
                    a += stride;
                    b = a - bytesPerPixel;
                    if (index >= pixelIndexF.Length)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                pixelIndexF[index] = i * bytesPerPixel;
                pixelIndexB[index++] = b;
            }
        }

        Parallel.For(0, pixelIndexF.Length, new Action<int>(delegate(int i)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[bytesPerPixel];
            Buffer.BlockCopy(framePixels, pixelIndexF[i], buffer, 0, bytesPerPixel);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(framePixels, pixelIndexB[i], framePixels, pixelIndexF[i], bytesPerPixel);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, framePixels, pixelIndexB[i], bytesPerPixel);
        }));

        s.Stop();
        System.Console.WriteLine("ReverseFrameInPlace: {0}", s.Elapsed);
    }
```

**Revision #2**

```
    private void ReverseFrameInPlace(int width, int height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat pixelFormat, byte[] framePixels)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch s = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

        System.Drawing.Rectangle imageBounds = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(0,0,width, height);

        //create destination bitmap, get handle
        System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(width, height, pixelFormat);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(imageBounds, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);
        IntPtr ptr = bitmapData.Scan0;

        //byte[] to bmap
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(framePixels, 0, ptr, framePixels.Length);
        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

        //flip
        bitmap.RotateFlip(System.Drawing.RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipX);

        //get handle for bitmap to byte[]
        bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(imageBounds, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bitmap.PixelFormat);
        ptr = bitmapData.Scan0;
        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, framePixels, 0, framePixels.Length);
        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);

        s.Stop();
        System.Console.WriteLine("ReverseFrameInPlace: {0}", s.Elapsed);
    }
```

Comment: There is no point in using `ref`.

Comment: Is `unsafe` code an option for you?

Comment: This isn't exactly an answer, but often these kinds of problems are best solved in shaders when rendering those images (if you are rendering them in a context that uses a shader)

Answer (score 4):

I faced almost the same issue but in my case I needed to flip the image for saving it to an .avi container. 
I used the Array.Copy() method instead and suprisingly it seems faster than the others (at least, on my machine). The source image that I used was 720 x 576 pixels with 3 bytes per pixel. This method took between .001 - 0.01 seconds versus about 0.06 seconds for both your revisions.

```
    private byte[] ReverseFrameInPlace2(int stride, byte[] framePixels)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch s = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var reversedFramePixels = new byte[framePixels.Length];
        var lines = framePixels.Length / stride;

        for (var line = 0; line < lines; line++)
        {
            Array.Copy(framePixels, framePixels.Length - ((line + 1) * stride), reversedFramePixels, line * stride, stride);
        }

        s.Stop();
        System.Console.WriteLine("ReverseFrameInPlace2: {0}", s.Elapsed);
        return reversedFramePixels;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try calling [`Buffer.BlockCopy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx) on each range of 4 bytes; that should be faster.

Comment: I tried this a few ways - with a temp buffer for just the bytes being copied as well as a buffer copy of the entire stride.  There isn't much of a difference although it seems marginally faster.

Answer (score 2):

You could parallelize execution on the CPU using any technique or use a pixel shader and do it on the GPU. If you only do that to display flipped video - you would best use DirectX and simply do a transformation on the GPU.

Comment: I'm listening. :)  Haven't done much GPU/DirectX, able to point me to any resources or examples?

Comment: It really depends on your scenario - the exact goal you are trying to achieve, platform, languages you can use etc. Jeremiah Morrill just blogged about using GPU effects in an MFT here: http://jeremiahmorrill.wordpress.com/2012/04/25/gpu-accelerated-media-effects-in-windows-8-metro/. This is a sample for Windows 8 Metro Style Apps, but I think with some research you could find how to do the exact same thing in regular C++ applications running on Windows 7. This is for pixel shaders, although in your scenario you might not need a pixel shader.

Comment: You could use IMFMediaEngine::TransferVideoFrame (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh448021(v=vs.85).aspx) to render the video to a texture and use that texture in a Direct3D scene where the texture is applied to a rectangle flipped around the Y axis. I am just starting to play with DirectX myself and I don't have a sample at hand, but it should be fairly straightforward to modify some basic DirectX samples to achieve this. In result you could probably play 4 reversed videos at a time with good rendering performance leaving the bottleneck in the IO and GPU cooling.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.  I'll dig into it a little more over the next few days because I think offloading the work to the GPU will help me with other pieces I know are going to be CPU intensive.

Answer (score 1):

Couple more random things to try and measure:

- pre-build array of indexes to copy to for a line (like [12,13,14,15,  8,9,10,11, 4,5,6,7, 0,1,2,3] instead of some complicated ifs executed on each line.
- try copying to new destination instead of in-place.

Comment: New destination is slower than in place.  I'll give building an index array a whirl but I have a feeling it won't be faster.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: In place, with indexes and Buffer.BlockCopy about cuts the time in half (usually 0.05s-0.1s).  Tolerable, but would still love to find something faster. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use one of the many transforms supplied by the .NET library:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970271.aspx

Edit: Here's another example:

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-rotate

Comment: That was my initial approach and it crawled.

Comment: It looks like you are using array indexes to access the data.  It might be faster with 'unsafe' pointers (you indicated unsafe is OK) as described in this article: http://www.bobpowell.net/lockingbits.htm

Comment: Actually, I was just revisiting this and trying it again, and it looks like using Marshal.Copy to copy the bytes to/from a bitmap and doing a RotateFlip does perform significantly better than the current implementation I have.  Posting the current one up as well - feel free to critique, its memory usage is all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

Another option might be to use the XNA framework to do manipulations on images.  There is a small example of [How to resize and save a Texture2D in XNA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664279/how-to-resize-and-save-a-texture2d-in-xna).  I have no idea how fast it is, but I could see how it should be pretty fast considering the functions are suppose to be used in games with high fps.